# azure site wont scale down from basic as incorrectly reporting size

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have two asp.net core apps which both are deployed via github integration directly to their own respective azure websites. One site has a custom domain and the other doesn't.

When initally configuring the integration on both sites they initially failed with space related warnings. So i scaled the sites to be a basic(1 small). I don't know 
why i needed to do this as both the apps are considerably less than the 1G which i believe a shared webapp has as a limit. (the two sites on my local HDD are 117M and 120M respectively)

As a result of this i have two sites both sharing the same service plan which is a £41 a month rather than having one site on free and the other on a shared £7 a month(as it needs a custom domain)

If i try and scale down the serviceplan i get the following error. (redacted as expected)

```
{
"authorization": null,
"caller": null,
"channels": null,
"claims": {},
"correlationId": null,
"description": "Failed to update App Service plan defaultserviceplan: {\"Code\":\"Conflict\",\"Message\":\"Storage usage quota exceeded. Cannot update or delete a server farm.\",\"Target\":null,\"Details\":[{\"Message\":\"Storage usage quota exceeded. Cannot update or delete a server farm.\"},{\"Code\":\"Conflict\"},{\"ErrorEntity\":{\"ExtendedCode\":\"11006\",\"MessageTemplate\":\"Storage usage quota exceeded. Cannot update or delete a server farm.\",\"Parameters\":[],\"InnerErrors\":[],\"Code\":\"Conflict\",\"Message\":\"Storage usage quota exceeded. Cannot update or delete a server farm.\"}}],\"Innererror\":null}",
"eventDataId": null,
"eventName": null,
"eventSource": null,
"category": null,
"eventTimestamp": "Wed Jun 21 2017 11:01:25 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)",
"id": "Failed to update App Service plan_Wed Jun 21 2017 11:01:25 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)",
"level": "1",
"operationId": null,
"operationName": {
    "value": "Failed to update App Service plan",
    "localizedValue": "Failed to update App Service plan"
},
"resourceGroupName": null,
"resourceProviderName": null,
"resourceType": null,
"resourceId": null,
"status": {
    "value": "Error",
    "localizedValue": "Error"
},
"subStatus": null,
"submissionTimestamp": null,
"subscriptionId": null,
"properties": {
    "correlationIds": "REDACTED"
},
"relatedEvents": []
```

}

How can i diagnose what is taking up the space, or report this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to look at is your file-system usage. You can look at what the App Service thinks you are using by going to the App Service plan and clicking on filesystem on the left hand menu.

[image]

This will give you an aggregated view of how much space is being used by all apps in the App Service plan.

if this value is > 1 GiB then you won't be able to scale down to shared (I suspect this is what causing your issue)

The next step would be to look at the storage used by each of the apps in your App Service plan.

In the Web App UX you should be able to go to "Quota" and see what each app in the App Service plan is using.

If you find an app that using more space than you think it should be using, a here are a few things to look at:

- Logs: if you are logging to the app's filesystem this can use up space quickly depending on the verbosity level.
- MySQL In App: if you have enabled this feature, the db is stored as a file on disk, and will use up space as well.

  - Site extensions installed on your app

You should be able to use Kudu and the debug console to get a good idea of what is using space.

Comment: ok so the appservice plan says 1.03GiB. site a(without custom domain) using 0.63GiB and siteb(with custom domain) using 0.4GiB. ( both figures feel high anyway as they are 4 and 3 times more space on azure than local. And neither have anything switched on other than the default optons, so no local databases or custom logging. when i choose the option change service plan on site a so i can move it to an existing shared service plan, the list is empty.

Comment: ok so managed to fix it, deleted old shared plan (empty) and added a new free plan. moved site a into plan, then i could downgrade the other plan to a shared. The problem (it seems ) originated from me having to have a beefier plan when i did the initial restore (github integration) i suspect its todo with webpack/npm. Both sites are very basic modifications from stevesandersons javascriptservices spa tool. And both initially failed when they were running the npm/webpack tasks. wouldnt be surprised if the restore took both sites over a gig with temp files when doing the initial restore.

Comment: Encountered storage issues post-library upgrade, traced to surplus runtimes. Resolved effectively using Kudu PowerShell console to remove these runtimes, freeing up necessary space. Useful insight for similar storage challenges.